# select an option using javascript on success of request

Tags: javascript, html, selectedindex, selectedindexchanged

select day , month and year by jsondata

```
success: function(jsondata){

            var data=JSON.parse(jsondata);

                var list_html="<div id='editrelation'><label id='dateLabel' style='display:none'>Since/Anniversary</label><select style='display:none' id='month' class=''  aria-label='Month' name='month'><option value='-1'>Month:</option><option value='1'>Jan</option><option value='2'>Feb</option><option value='3'>Mar</option><option value='4'>Apr</option><option value='5'>May</option><option value='6'>Jun</option><option value='7'>Jul</option><option value='8'>Aug</option><option value='9'>Sep</option><option value='10'>Oct</option><option value='11'>Nov</option><option value='12'>Dec</option></select><select id='day' class='' aria-label='Day' name='day'  style='display:none; margin-left: 74px; margin-top: -25px;'><option value='-1'>Day:</option>";
                for(var i=1;i<=31;i++){
                list_html+="<option value="+i+" id='d"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
                }
                list_html+="</select><select style='display:none; margin-top: -25px; margin-left: 130px;' id='year' class='' aria-label='Year' name='year'><option value='-1'>Year:</option>";
                    for(var i=2014;i>=1914;i--){
                        list_html+="<option value="+i+" id="+i+">"+i+"</option>";
                        }
                list_html+="</select>"
                list_html+="</div>";
                document.getElementById('form_relation').innerHTML=list_html;
                if(data['date']!=undefined){//data['date']='1/24/1990'
                    var ani=data['date'];
                    var dateArray=ani.split("/");
                    var month=dateArray[0];
                    var day=dateArray[1];
                    var year=dateArray[2];
                        document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex =month;
                        document.getElementById("day").selectedIndex =day;
                        document.getElementById("year").selectedIndex =year;

                }
}
```

below line is not working

```
document.getElementById("year").selectedIndex =year;
```

Comment: What is your question ? What is your problem ?

Comment: select a option using javascript

Comment: .selectedIndex  works for month and day but not for year

Comment: not working this line
document.getElementById("year").selectedIndex =year;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with 'value'

```
document.getElementById("month").value =month;
document.getElementById("day").value=day;
document.getElementById("year").value=year;
```

Comment: What about `document.getElementById('form_relation').innerHTML=list_html;` ?

Comment: document.getElementById('form_relation').innerHTML=list_html, form_relation is a div,where these will show

Comment: Yep indeed... will remove my wrong comment

Comment: innerHTML  is using for adding/ displaying a content to a html tags like div,p etc

Answer (score 0):

This can't work. In 2 words, the elements you're trying to access are not in the DOM, they're not even in the document yet, so there's no way to get it through `getElementById()`.
you should remove the whole loop building those elements and simply put them in the page, they don't use the returned data anyway...

Comment: document.getElementById('form_relation').innerHTML=list_html; already enter it to inner Html of a div

Comment: Oups, my bad, indeed. Then we'll need more info on what is actually "not working".

Comment: Also, those are waaaaaay more than 2 words ;)